# PHP CLI errors from unix commands

Tags: php, shell, unix, exec, command-line-interface

I am writing php script, which will be used for making sites from "standart" site.
There's a lot of unix shell commands, and I've found the problem with displaying errors.

Example: I need to check that the site folder doesn't exist yet.

```
$ls_newsite = exec('ls /vhosts/'.$sitename, $output, $error_code);
if ($error_code == 0) {
    Shell::error('This site already exists in /vhosts/');
}
Shell::output(sprintf("%'.-37s",$sitename).'OK!');
```

So, I can handle error, but it will be display anyway.

```
php shell.php testing.com

Checking site...
ls: cannot access /vhosts/testing.com: No such file or directory
testing.com.................................OK!
```

How can I prevent displaying? Thanks

Comment: As @Colin Morelli said, you don't need to use console commands for this. `file_exists` will suffice.

Comment: It's just example to show problem.

Comment: But even so, there aren't very many cases you should be using the `exec` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the output from these CLI calls, just the error code. So direct your output to `/dev/null` (otherwise PHP will print whatever goes to `stderr` unless you use `proc_open` and create pipes for each of these - overkill).

```
$ls_newsite = exec('ls /vhosts/' . $sitename . ' > /dev/null 2>&1', $output, $error_code);
```

That will work without giving you any output.

Now, on to a few other issues:

**Use `escapeshellarg` for anything you're passing to a shell command.**
A better way to write this same code is:

```
$ls_newsite = exec(sprintf('ls %s > /dev/null 2>&1', escapeshellarg('/vhosts/' . $sitename)), $output, $error_code);
```

**Be 100% sure that you need to use console commands.** There are PHP equivalents for most file-based console commands (`stat`, `file_exists`, `is_dir`, etc) that would make your code both more secure *and* would allow it to be platform-independent.